# Evans' proof of parabolic strong maximum principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading his PDE in chapter 7.1 the last theorem is about   the strong maximum principle for parabolic equation when $c\geq 0$ at page 398. I have some problem at the second step:

Since $u_t +Ku=-cu\leq 0$ on $\{ u\geq 0 \}$, we deduce from the weak maximum principle that $u\leq v$.

Who can give some detail to show how the weak maximum principle applies? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand,
$$
u_t + K u \leq 0
$$
on $\{ u \geq 0\}$.
On the other hand,
$$
v_t + K v = 0,
$$
with $v = u^+$ on $\Delta_T$.

If we subtract second equation from the first one, we get
$$
(u-v)_t + K(u-v) \leq 0 \quad \implies \quad
w_t + K w \leq 0,
$$
where $w := u-v$. (We can do that, since $\frac{d}{dt}$ and $K$ are linear operators).
Moreover, $w = 0$ on $\Delta_T$.

Hence, applying Weak Maximum Principle for $w$ (Theorem 8), we obtain
$$
\max_{W_T} w = \max_{\Delta_T} w = 0,
$$
and therefore, $w \leq 0$. Thus, $u \leq v$.

Comment: @Ylath Note that, due to the nonnegative boundary conditions, by Weak maximum principle $0 \leq v$ in $W_T$. If $u < 0$ somewhere in $W_T$, then $u < 0 \leq v$ automatically.